# Remove value from comma separated list and turn it back into string

Tags: ruby, csv

My goal is to convert list into array using split method then remove element(depends) from it and turning back again array into string using join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

```
list = "a,b,c,d"
list.split(",").select{|elem| elem != "b"}.join(",")
```

This just removes "b" from the list, but you can adapt the `{|elem|...}` block for your needs. Just return false to remove an element.

Comment: Yeah Sorry it is ruby, I am very new to ruby. right now we can se array elements what if where we can select any value randomly, I mean then how we will adjust {|elem|...}

Answer (score 1):

To add to `user576875`'s answer, and your follow-up, you can just pass a block along to select. For instance:

```
def remove str, &block
    str.split(',').select(&block).join(',')
end

s = "a,b,c,d"
puts s       #=> 'a,b,c,d'
t = remove(s) {|elm| elm != 'b' }
puts t       #=> 'a,c,d'
```

Comment: If this is real CSV data, just splitting on a comma is not enough. Consider `str = "foo,bar,"jim,jam,job",jee"`. Since Ruby has a CSV library included, you should use this.